# What does a wishing well do in crossroads?

Tags: project-spark

When playing a crossroads game, I can put down a wishing well as one of the quests.  When interacting with it, I can offer a number of coins to throw in.  What ate the rewards for doing this? Are there better rewards the more you throw in?